# I get an error when I use BroadcastUpdatePlugin (workbox-broadcast-update)

Tags: workbox

I want to use BroadcastUpdatePlugin (workbox-broadcast-update) in my application, but I have an error something like this:

[image]

My route:

```
registerRoute(
        /my regexp/,
        new StaleWhileRevalidate({
            plugins: [
                new BroadcastUpdatePlugin({
                    headersToCheck: ['etag']
                }),
            ],
        })
    );
```

Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the response doesn't have the etag header. You can check the request and the response headers in the dev tools.